# implementing curry function

Tags: haskell, composition, currying

I'm currently reading "programming in haskell" by Graham Hutton and just reached currying and function composition.In the exercise portion, there is the task to implement the curry function from scratch which is already present in the prelude module.

Here's my implementation but it's not working.Can anybody explain(I'm new to functional programming) why it's not working

```
my_curry :: ((a ,b) -> c) -> (a -> b -> c)
my_curry origFunc = origFunc.combine
                    where
                         combine e f = (e, f)
```

here's the error [added]

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( higher_order.hs, interpreted )

  higher_order.hs:92:30:
      Couldn't match type `t0 -> (a, t0)' with `(a, b)'
      Expected type: a -> (a, b)
        Actual type: a -> t0 -> (a, t0)
      In the second argument of `(.)', namely `combine'
      In the expression: origFunc . combine
      In an equation for `my_curry':
          my_curry origFunc
            = origFunc . combine
            where
                combine e f = (e, f)
```

Comment: -1 -- "not working" doesn't have a meaning. Clarify what do you mean: 1) Does the code compile? (if not why didn't you post the error you got?) 2) Does the program return an unexpected result? (Why didn't you post the result you got and what was the result you expected?) 3) Does the program crash or fail in some other way? (Why didn't you describe it?).

Comment: Just a note that in the future you'll get answers [even] more quickly if you give a bit more details about what exactly went wrong with the code ie what the error message was. Otherwise we both have to figure out what's wrong and then fix it, which isn't always possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that `.` is meant to take to single argument functions and glue them together,

In this case `combine` has the type `a -> b -> (a, b)`. So it's first argument is `a` and it's return type is `b -> (a, b)` (remember that `->` groups to the right). So `.` has the type

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a  -> c
```

Since `combine` is the second argument haskell is going to unify `.`s type variables like

```
(.).a ~ combine.a
(.).b ~ (combine.b -> (combine.a, combine.b))
```

I'm using `foo.bar` to mean the type variable `bar` from the definition of `foo`. Next we feed this into `origFunc` which as the type `(a, b) -> c`. Now when we try to fit this into `.` we get

```
(.).b ~ my_curry.(a, b)
(.).c ~ my_curry.c
```

But wait! `b` can't be both `(a, b)` and `b -> (a, b)` and thus the type error.

Instead we have two choices, we can create a new type of composition

```
(..) :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
f .. g = \a b -> f (g a b)
```

Notice how this allows `g` to take two arguments, and your function becomes

```
 my_curry origFunc = combine .. origFunc
```

Or we can just use currying

```
 my_curry origFunc x y = origFunc (x, y)
```

Comment: Yet another way to do this composition is `my_curry origFunc = (origFunc.) . combine`.

Comment: @JohnL Definitely, I'm not sure that that's appropriate for a Haskell beginner though

Answer (score 5):

jozefg's answer explained why your code doesn't work, and I thought I'd contribute a fairly straightforward implementation for you to see.

Notice the function signature for `my_curry` is `((a, b) -> c) -> (a -> b -> c)`. It takes in a function, and it returns a function as the result. We can capture the notion of "returning a function" easily with a lambda expression:

```
my_curry func = \x y -> func (x, y)
```

All this code does is takes in a single function on the left side of the equals sign, and returns a new function on the right hand side. The function it returns takes in its arguments one at a time, tuples them up and fires them off to whatever function we passed in.

Another way we can look at this is by removing the brackets in the type signature. Since the arrow in a type signature is right-associative, the type of `my_curry` can also be written as `((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c`. In this form, we can see that we can also implement `my_curry` as a function taking three arguments: the input function, and an x and a y to tuple-up and send through that function. Therefore another valid way to write the function is

```
my_curry func x y = func (x, y)
```